# PIL in py2exe: 'no module named Image'

Tags: python, py2exe, python-imaging-library

I've a working python-script in which **Image** from **Pillow** is imported succesfully.

Like this: *'from PIL import Image'*

After using **py2exe** and including PIL like any other Library, follwing error occurs:

*'No module named Image'*

All other Libraries seem to be work.

I already found this solution: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/py2exeAndPIL

But it does not seem to fix my problem.Is there another possibility to tell py2exe to include 'Image' and all other needed parts from Pillow?

Thank you in advance,
Nico

Comment: um... Pillow is the ‘friendly’ PIL fork by Alex Clark and Contributors. PIL is the Python Imaging Library by Fredrik Lundh and Contributors.

Comment: Hey, yes that's true. But when you unzip the Pillow-egg, you can see that the library is still available by using 'PIL'. The script is working, py2exe is the only troublemaker.

Comment: I haven't got much experience on Windows machines, I was just trying to suggest if this is the case of `from Pillow import Image` rather than `PIL`

Comment: I would be very happy if anyone who already had to deal with a problem like this (py2exe did not include a library properly) would tell me how he finally fixed it. But thank you that you wanted to help, Anzel.

Answer (score 0):

You can add PIL to your py2exe setup options, either in packages or includes:

```
setup (
  options = {"py2exe": {...
                        "packages": ["PIL"], # For everything
                        "includes": ["PIL.Image", # Or here for bits and pieces 
                                     "PIL.PngImagePlugin"]}},
  name="foo",
  ...
  )
```